# Is it possible for Python to display LaTex in real time in a text box?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I plan on making a GUI where the user would input their mathematical expressions into a text box, such as Tkinter Entry Widget, and their expressions would be displayed in the same manner as you would see when you type your expressions in [symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com).

Is this possible? If so, then what modules do I have to use in order to accomplish this?

Comment: You would have better luck trying to get MathJax to work inside your application. TeX is a large distribution.

Comment: Alright, I will check that out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This question is way too broad. I'm not overly sure should it be closed for that matter. Nontheless, here's a snippet on how to, at least, get latex working with Tk and matplotlib interactively.

Enter something in the Entry widget and press enter.

```py
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk

def graph(event=None):
    tmptext = entry.get()
    tmptext = "$"+tmptext+"$"

    ax.clear()
    ax.text(0.2, 0.6, tmptext, fontsize=50)  
    canvas.draw()

root = tk.Tk()

mainframe = tk.Frame(root)
mainframe.pack()

entry = tk.Entry(mainframe, width=70)
entry.pack()

label = tk.Label(mainframe)
label.pack()

fig = matplotlib.figure.Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=label)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

entry.insert(0, r"\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_i \frac{y_i}{z_i}")
graph()

root.bind("<Return>", graph)
root.mainloop()
```

code should produce a window such as one bellow:

[image]

If you want to have a nice interface like theirs this will not be enough. They most likely have something like a plaintext to Latex to Unicode conversion setup. Or even perhaps directly from plaintext to Unicode but I am not aware of any parser for math expressions as nice as latex so all the rules would presumably have to be re-coded and that's a lot of work so they most likely skipped that step and instead let latex do the heavy lifting and then just parse latex to Unicode/Utf8 or whichever encoding can handle all the signs.

Then they dumped everything through something "extra" (i.e. django and jinja templating) that assigns each element its own nice css class based on the type of element (binary operator, variable, exponent...) in order to have the full math output that looks nice and can still be copied.

In any case there's so much going on in this question it's not really possible to give a concise all-encompassing easy answer.

Comment: That is not TeX output. That's an approximation.

Comment: @SeanAllred; You are right, that is the mathtext rendering from matplotlib which is faster but with less options. If the OP wants to use Latex rendering s/he should set the text.usetex : True in matplotlib's rc settings. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a solution that uses `sympy`. It was partly inspired by an answer to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/8paczw/displaying_mathematics_in_gui_application/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) subreddit. In particular it uses the [`sympy.printing.preview`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/printing.html#preview) method.

This is the import part

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

from tkinter import *
import sympy as sp
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from io import BytesIO
```

Then I define the GUI, pretty standard stuff. I didn't put too much effort into it

```py
class Root():
    def __init__(self, master):
        #Define the main window and the relevant widgets
        self.master = master
        master.geometry("800x300")
        self.strvar = StringVar()
        self.label = Label(master)
        self.entry = Entry(master, textvariable = self.strvar, width = 80)
        self.button = Button(text = "LaTeX!", command = self.on_latex)
        #The Euler product formula
        self.strvar.set("\prod_{p\,\mathrm{prime}}\\frac1{1-p^{-s}} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \\frac1{n^s}")

        #Pack everything
        self.entry.pack()
        self.button.pack()
        self.label.pack()
```

Then let's define the function that renders `LaTeX` (keep the indentation)

```py
    def on_latex(self):
        expr = "$\displaystyle " + self.strvar.get() + "$"

        #This creates a ByteIO stream and saves there the output of sympy.preview
        f = BytesIO()
        the_color = "{" + self.master.cget('bg')[1:].upper()+"}"
        sp.preview(expr, euler = False, preamble = r"\documentclass{standalone}"
                   r"\usepackage{pagecolor}"
                   r"\definecolor{graybg}{HTML}" + the_color +
                   r"\pagecolor{graybg}"
                   r"\begin{document}",
                   viewer = "BytesIO", output = "ps", outputbuffer=f)
        f.seek(0)
        #Open the image as if it were a file. This works only for .ps!
        img = Image.open(f)
        #See note at the bottom
        img.load(scale = 10)
        img = img.resize((int(img.size[0]/2),int(img.size[1]/2)),Image.BILINEAR)
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        self.label.config(image = photo)
        self.label.image = photo
        f.close()
```

I choose the document class `standalone` in order to adapt the size of the produced document to its content. Then I use the package [`pagecolor`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pagecolor) to make the page blend seamlessly with the background. Notice also that `PIL` is not compatible with every [format](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html#image-file-formats). Choosing an output of .pdf, for instance, will generate an error when defining `img` and choosing .png will give problems when defining `photo`. The format .ps works well and it's also vectorial, which is nice.

Finally one needs

```py
master = Tk()
root   = Root(master)
master.mainloop()
```

This is what it looks like

[image: Latex]

---

<sub>**Note**:
There I scaled the picture up by 10 and scaled it down by 1/2. This is only because it looks a bit smoother and nicer, but it's not needed. The first scaling uses the vectorial nature of the .ps format so it doesn't lose resolution, while the second scaling acts on the rasterized image.</sub>

Comment: What to do for "RuntimeError:latex program is not installed"?

Comment: If you write a .tex file by hand and compile it with `pdflatex` on the terminal does it produce an output?

Comment: Yes it does,but there I mentioned the full path where the pdflatex.exe is located by compiler=<path>.Only then it outputs a tex file and a .pdf.How can i modify the above code to mention the path?I think that will solve the problem

Comment: If you look at the [source code](https://docs.sympy.org/1.0/_modules/sympy/printing/preview.html) it uses the function [find_executable](https://docs.sympy.org/1.0/_modules/sympy/utilities/misc.html) to find the executable. It looks for the paths in the `PATH` environment variable. I am not sure how to edit it on Windows, but it's very googlable [(e.g.)](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).

Comment: It's nice to see Matplotlib free solution here. Bonus points: for  conversion of `sympy` expression straight to image. Minuses: coloring didn't work for me, it has tried to install `pagecolor` and crashed with error (RuntimeError: 'latex' exited abnormally with the following output). Also, I needed to change option to `png` because it crashed wit error (`OSError: Unable to locate Ghostscript on paths`).

Comment: As a solution, I have removed 2-4 lines from latex preamble.

Comment: If you simply do a latex document using `pagecolor` (in the normal way, without python), does the compiler still complain about the missing package?

Comment: Install of `pagecolor` was successfull, it crashed after reruns. The most probably this is because `the_color` is set to `YSTEMBUTTONFACE` which is not recognized in `latex`. I think it should be some hexadecimal number instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is a working example (python2, raspbian), although it is not very elegant.  This is one solution among a multitude, but it shows all the steps from the latex source file to the Tkinter program.

```py
from subprocess import call
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk

TEX = (  # use raw strings for backslash
  r"\documentclass{article}",
  r"\begin{document}",
  r"$$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$$",
  r"$$x=\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$$",
  r"\end{document}",
)

with open("doc1.tex", "w") as file:
    file.write("\n".join(TEX))

call(["latex", "doc1.tex"])
call(["dvips", "doc1.dvi", "-o", "doc1.ps"])
call(["gs", "-sDEVICE=ppmraw", "-dNOPAUSE", "-dBATCH", "-dSAFER", "-sOutputFile=doc1.ppm", "doc1.ps"])

root1 = tk.Tk()
img1 = tk.PhotoImage(file="doc1.ppm")
label1 = tk.Label(root1, image=img1)
label1.pack()
root1.mainloop()
```

There are a lot of possible variations: compile latex to pdf instead of ps; use other image file formats; use library PIL to support other formats, etc.

This solution is also **very inefficient** (don't tell me, I know). For example, on my system, the `ppm` file is 1,5Mb.  The equations also appear in the middle of a big page (it would need to be cropped).

Even if it needs improvement, it answers your question (display a LaTeX document in a Tkinter program) and should give you a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions:

- Convert Tex to pdf/image in the backend and render the image instead
- Text rendering with Latex using [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html#usetex-tutorial)