# Displaying Latex in python - matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, latex

guys. I'm trying to build something similar to the image. I'm using sympy and I had read that I needed to install Latex, which I did. Nevertheless, I'm not sure about how to use it or implement it in my code. I know it works because I copied- pasted these [codes](https://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html) in my text editor and It worked. But in these examples Latex is only included in the Labels and the title. I would like to go the extramile and use it in my code. How should I import this library?

I'm truly stuck, any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance and have a good day!

[image]

Comment: You want to display this equation on your plot? What do you mean by **use it in my code**? Since you have tagged matplotlib, I assume you want to show them within your plot area. In that case, you could use `plt.text`

Comment: Yes, @Bazingaa. I want to make a calculator for derivatives and I would like my text to be displayed in that way.

Comment: Ok, check ym answer. I don't know what you mean by "I want to make a calculator for derivatives" but as far as displaying the equation on plot is concerned, below is one way

Comment: Not exactly in my plot because I would follow the examples. I will create a calculator for derivatives and the input of a function will be something like *sin(x**2)/exp(sqrt(x))* , however, I do not want to display it in that way because it is more likely to make mistakes. I would like a neater syntax

Comment: An alternative would be to embed an HTML browser as the window in your calculator, and then use https://www.mathjax.org/ for displaying the LaTex results from Sympy.

Comment: I am sorry but I am unable to understand what you are trying to say and what exactly you want. Perhaps other readers would answer you. If my answer is not what you wanted, leave a comment below the answer and I will delete my answer

Comment: @Bazingaa I think that your answer gives me a hint about what I should do. I will be  more explicit. I use Entry () to display the results in my calculator. In this case, I want to show the function that my user wants to derive, which is exactly what you showed in the answer, but for my particular program, I will do it in the screen rather than a plot.

Answer (score 0):

I kept researching and I was able to find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36636185/is-it-possible-for-python-to-display-latex-in-real-time-in-a-text-box) which is pretty similar to what I want. I will try to work using this as an example and I will update in case that I get the results I'm looking for.