# Changing user input to a mathematical equation in Tkinter

Tags: python, math, tkinter, latex, tk-toolkit

I am making an app with Tkinter that tests school students ability to solve algebraic equations.

Currently the app gets students to solve simple equations such as (3x - 4 = 5x - 10). The app shows students an equation, asks them to input some working out and then input a solution.

I've successfully managed to do the above with the tkinter.Enter widget; however, the font of the text they input looks bad and clunky (I have changed the input font to Times). It looks especially bad when students input a fraction, e.g. 4x/3 + 5/4 = 1/2.

What I want is for these boxes to convert what they have written into a font commonly used for mathematical equation (something like the mathematical symbols in LaTeX).

Is there a way I can do this?

Open to all sorts of suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Hey, I was wondering if you might be able to use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59205881/5210078 and then possibly have the students use something like the [online LaTeX equation editor](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php), libreoffice maths or symbolab to make the equations? I am not sure if that is exactly what you would want though

Comment: I wouldn't use a serif font like Times.   Assuming Windows, try Arial.    As to the other question, perhaps create a little .html file with MathJax in it, and open it with the user's browser.