# How to use LaTeX typesetting in TKinter Label texts

Tags: python, tkinter, latex, tkinter-entry

I have some Labels in TKinter, with label text such as Jx. However, this is intended to be $J_x$ and rendered according to standard LaTeX typesetting. For example, consider this **MWE:**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.font as font
from tkinter import Tk
from turtle import bgcolor

import tkinter as tk

class UI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        helv15 = font.Font(family="Helvetica",size=15,weight="bold")
        self.JxEntryLabel = Label(self.master, text = "Jx :", bg = 'white', fg = fontcolor, font = helv15)
        self.JxEntryLabel.place(relheight = 0.05, relwidth = 0.1, relx = 0.15, rely = 0.15) 

root=Tk()
app=UI(root)
root.title('Test_UI')
root.geometry("1200x600")
root.configure(background='white')

root.mainloop()
```

How can I edit/add to this MWE to ensure the `Label` button text typesets using LaTeX such that the x is a subscript to J and it is in math font? i.e. typing $J_x$ just shows $J_x$. For `Matplotlib` this is usual quite easy to achieve for plots, but I am not sure how to use the same tricks here.

**Note:** this question is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36636185/is-it-possible-for-python-to-display-latex-in-real-time-in-a-text-box) post, where the objective was to take latex input and display it in realtime, though I believe that parts of the answer can be reused to answer this question. However, I am not sure how. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So youre fine using the matplotlib backend, but want to display the text inside a Label instead of an embedded figure?

Comment: @mnikley Displaying the text is preferred, but if embedding a figure is the only route, then I would be happy to explore that route too

Comment: Some elements of answer with this question and answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36636185/is-it-possible-for-python-to-display-latex-in-real-time-in-a-text-box.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use Matplotlib for the typesetting. The way I understand it is you could do:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.text(0, 0, r"whatever latex text")
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = tkinter_window)

canvas.draw()

canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
```

This creates a Matplotlib figure containing only the LaTeX text, and adds it to `tkinter_window`.